# DynamoDB query and filter based on if a set attribute contains any of the element

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, amazon-dynamodb-data-modeling

I have a table that looks something like the below, which contains some entity and it's ACL.

Source - PartitionKey
Neighbour - SortKey
ACL - Set of Strings

Now, say I'm given a list of permissions a user have, is there a way for me to query by partition key, which will then return all the <source, neighbor> item collections, but filter it such that only items where user has permission is returned? (The user's list of permission has at least one element that is in the item's ACL).

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible without using a Scan operation, as you are trying to search on a list of attributes. An index will also not work as you can't index in list attributes.